# Multiple Triggers and Setting Value to Not Empty

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, textbox

I want to set the background of the Search TextBox to `Transparent` when it lose focus instead of `White`. Currently, when the search box is not focused, the background will be set to the VisualBrush that show the gray string `Search`.

How to use Multiple Trigger to set the background color when `IsKeyboardFocused` is False and the `Text` is not empty?

[image]

```
<!-- Search Input Box -->
<TextBox Name="SearchInputBox" Grid.Column="1" BorderThickness="0" Foreground="#CAFFFFFF" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
         FontSize="18" CaretBrush="White" Height="25.94" Margin="0,6.541">

    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox" xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">



            <Style.Resources>
                <!-- Search Background -->
                <VisualBrush x:Key="CueBannerBrush" AlignmentX="Left" AlignmentY="Center" Stretch="None">
                    <VisualBrush.Visual>
                        <Label Content="Search" FontSize="18" Foreground="#AEFFFFFF" Background="Transparent"/>
                    </VisualBrush.Visual>
                </VisualBrush>
            </Style.Resources>



            <!-- Triggers -->
            <Style.Triggers>

                <!-- No Input, Show Search -->
                <Trigger Property="Text" Value="{x:Static sys:String.Empty}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource CueBannerBrush}" />
                </Trigger>

                <!--- Null Input, Show Search -->
                <Trigger Property="Text" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource CueBannerBrush}" />
                </Trigger>

                <!-- Typing, Hide Search -->
                <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                </Trigger>

                <!-- Lose Focus and Not Typing -->
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding IsKeyboardFocused}" Value="False"/>
                        <!--<Condition Binding="{Binding Text}"/>-->
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                </MultiDataTrigger>

            </Style.Triggers>



        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a converter that can return a value indicating if a string is null or empty in your binding to `Text` property. But firstly, I suppose the binding source should be fixed like this:

```
<Condition Binding="{Binding IsKeyboardFocused, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}" Value="False" />
```

It works for me by changing the source to the control itself.

Then, create a converter:

```
public class NotNullOrEmptyStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value.ToString());
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

After that, add the converter to resource dictionary, then add the other condition like this:

```
<Condition Binding="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Converter={StaticResource NotNullOrEmptyStringConverter}}" Value="True" />
```